# 2013 Workflow - Sending email to multiple users from People Picker in InfoPath form

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have set up a workflow that will email a person or persons in a People Picker field that allows multiple values. However, the Workflow doesn't work and shows this error:

```
RequestorId: 64fb8be0-4f83-3135-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.InvalidCastException: The value 'd/results(0)/residentsId' cannot be read as type 'String'. at Microsoft.Activities.GetDynamicValueProperty`1.CheckedRead(String propertyName, DynamicItem value) at Microsoft.Activities.GetDynamicValueProperty`1.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity`1.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

With some research, I saw that it was related to how the email addresses get formatted for People Picker fields that allow multiple users. I implemented the fix of changing the Return field as to Display Names, semicolon delimited and Login Names, semicolon delimited, but neither of them work still. Images below are of my workflow and list settings.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqNE1.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuwyT.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7eaN.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrAid.png

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the field value retur as email.

Use log to history to debug the data also.

[image]

Comment: I have done this. I have also logged with what shows up when the look up is set to this and it shows the email address as normal. I am still not sure why it's not sending an email if the email address field is set properly,